# Implementing snapshot in FRP

Tags: scala, haskell, programming-languages, semantics, frp

I'm implementing an FRP framework in Scala and I seem to have run into a problem. Motivated by some thinking, this question I decided to restrict the public interface of my framework so Behaviours could only be evaluated in the 'present' i.e.:

```
behaviour.at(now)
```

This also falls in line with Conal's assumption in the Fran paper that Behaviours are only ever evaluated/sampled at increasing times. It does restrict transformations on Behaviours but otherwise we find ourselves in huge problems with Behaviours that represent some input:

```
val slider = Stepper(0, sliderChangeEvent)
```

With this Behaviour, evaluating future values would be incorrect and evaluating past values would require an unbounded amount of memory (all occurrences used in the 'slider' event would have to be stored).

I am having trouble with the specification for the 'snapshot' operation on Behaviours given this restriction. My problem is best explained with an example (using the slider mentioned above):

```
val event = mouseB // an event that occurs when the mouse is pressed 
val sampler = slider.snapshot(event) 
val stepper = Stepper(0, sampler)
```

My problem here is that if the 'mouseB' Event has occurred when this code is executed then the current value of 'stepper' will be the last 'sample' of 'slider' (the value at the time the last occurrence occurred). If the time of the last occurrence is in the past then we will consequently end up evaluating 'slider' using a past time which breaks the rule set above (and your original assumption). I can see a couple of ways to solve this:

1. We 'record' the past (keep hold of all past occurrences in an Event) allowing evaluation of Behaviours with past times (using an unbounded amount of memory)
2. We modify 'snapshot' to take a time argument ("sample after this time") and enforce that that time >= now
3. In a more wacky move, we could restrict creation of FRP objects to the initial setup of a program somehow and only start processing events/input after this setup is complete

I could also simply not implement 'sample' or remove 'stepper'/'switcher' (but I don't really want to do either of these things). Has anyone any thoughts on this? Have I misunderstood anything here?

Comment: You are aware of [Reactive](http://www.reactive-web.co.cc/), aren't you?

Comment: Reactive is cool but it breaks a few ideas in FRP. For instance it doesn't have a notion of continuous Behaviours: Signals in Reactive change discretely in time between different values. I was originally was confused how this fit into FRP and asked this question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451317/is-the-signal-representation-of-functional-reactive-programming-correct

Comment: Also, Reactive doesn't actually have any functionality like 'snapshot' as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I see what you mean now.

Your "you can only sample at 'now'" restriction isn't tight enough, I think.  It needs to be a bit stronger to avoid looking into the past.  Since you are using an environmental conception of `now`, I would define the behavior construction functions in terms of it (so long as `now` cannot advance by the mere execution of definitions, which, per my last answer, would get messy).  For example:

> `Stepper(i,e)` is a behavior with the value `i` in the interval `[now,e1]` (where `e1` is the
>   time of first occurrence of `e` after `now`), and the value of the most recent occurrence of `e` afterward.

With this semantics, your prediction about the value of `stepper` that got you into this conundrum is dismantled, and the stepper will now have the value 0.  I don't know whether this semantics is desirable to you, but it seems natural enough to me.

Comment: This is a really nice way of presenting it. I'm just getting frustrated with trying to find a way to maintain the original (lovely) semantics without using an unbounded amount of memory. I've noticed that some implementations remove 'stepper' and 'switcher' because of this but they seem so darn powerful. Ah well.

Comment: @seadowg, the Fran semantics are great, but we have so far failed to implement them efficiently (they always have such a space leak, and a corresponding slowness). I personally spent about 6 months on this problem.  We are also unable to determine any *reason* why it would be impossible, so a solution may still exist.  Suffice to say it will not be obvious.

Comment: @luqui: In [this blog post](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2012/01/01-frp-api-0-5.html), Heinrich Apfelmus points to [a paper](http://cs.ioc.ee/~tarmo/tsem10/jeltsch-slides.pdf) which supposedly gives an explanation for why the standard dynamic event switching type is inherently wrong. I'm not enough of an expert to understand it, but have you seen this, and if so, do you not find it convincing? (A bit off-topic, I know, but I assumed this would be well-known in the FRP community when I saw it.)

Comment: @ehird: Basically, the paper (actually slides) argues that FRP corresponds to a kind of *logic in the type system*, namely temporal logic. This is very beautiful. But to make it work, you have to add an additional type parameter and then you see that the original type of `switcher` is no good.

Comment: "Suffice to say it will not be obvious." Except in retrospect.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, you are worried about a race condition: what happens if an event occurs *while* the code is executing.

Purely functional code does not like to have to know that it gets executed.  Functional techniques are at their finest in the pure setting, such that it does not matter in what order code is executed.  A way out of this dilemma is to pretend that every change happened in one sensitive (internal, probably) piece of imperative code; pretend that any functional declarations in the FRP framework happen in 0 time so it is impossible for something to change during their declaration.

Nobody should ever sleep, or really do anything time sensitive, in a section of code that is *declaring* behaviors and things.  Essentially, code that works with FRP objects ought to be pure, then you don't have any problems.

This does not necessarily preclude running it on multiple threads, but to support that you might need to reorganize your internal representations. Welcome to the world of FRP library implementation -- I suspect your internal representation will fluctuate many times during this process. :-)

Comment: Interesting point. I'm not worried about whether something occurs while this code is executing (all that may be a problem) but if mouseB occurs before. Its simply that, given the definition of 'snapshot', the 'last' occurrence in the returned event would be (t, slider.at(t)) where t < now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about your confusion. The way I see is that `Stepper` will "set" the behavior to a new value whenever the event occurs. So, what happens is the following:

> The instant in which the event `mouseB` occurs, the value of the `slider` behavior will be read (`snapshot`). This value will be "set" into the behavior `stepper`.

So, it is true that the `Stepper` will "remember" values from the past; the point is that it only remembers the *latest* value from the past, not everything.

Semantically, it is best to model `Stepper` as a function like luqui proposes.

Comment: Yes if we aren't allowing past sampling. My problem was that if we call snapshot on a Behaviour using an Event that has occurrences in the past we will be sampling this Behaviour using a past time (which I don't want to allow). Stepper was used to aid the example.

Comment: @seadowg: Ah, I see. You have two options: either you make sure that at some point, the past was in the present, i.e. that you've "walked through the past occurrences already". Or you have to *trim* the past occurrences that you just now became aware of. These are the only ways to avoid a time leak (= remember an unbounded amount of data from the past). In general, accumulation and dynamic event switching cannot be combined freely, there have to be some restrictions.